# ORMLite SqlList with Tuples

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I'm having some troubles selecting a `Tuple` of Objects from my custom `SQL` query with `ORMLite`.

I have the following code:

```
var query = "select definition.*, timeslot.*, type.* from <blah blah>";
var defs = dbConnection.SqlList<Tuple<Definition, Timeslot, Type>>(query, new
                {
                    /* query parameters */
                });
```

The query itself is fine (I've tested it in SQL Management Studio).

The code above sets attributes only for the first item of the `Tuple`, leaving to the default state the others.

I've selected singularly each object and the result is correct (so no trouble during the conversion to `POCO` I guess).

Same thing goes if I use `Select<Tuple<Definition, Timeslot, Type>>` instead of `SqlList`.

I couldn't manage to try with `MultiSelect` since it appears to not take a string.

What is the correct way to select a `Tuple` in this manner?

I am working in `C#`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`SelectMulti` seems to be what you're looking for here.

From [the documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) under the **Selecting multiple columns across joined tables** heading:

```
// Note: I'm making an assumption on your query here.
// Build the `q` object however it needs to be.

var q = db.From<Definition>()
          .Join<Definition, Timeslot>()
          .Join<Definition, Type>();

var results = db.SelectMulti<Definition, Timeslot, Type>(q);

foreach (var tuple in results)
{
    var definition = tuple.Item1;
    var timeslot = tuple.Item2;
    var type = tuple.Item3;
}
```